# C# Idiomatic runtime expression which always evaluates to true but is not detected as compile-time constant

Tags: c#, compile-time-constant, constant-expression, unreachable-code, unused-variables

I would like to have a C# runtime expression which always evaluates to true, but which the compiler does not recognize as a constant. (Motivation below)   There are plenty of ways to achieve this, but I'm wondering if there's a nice most-idiomatic one.   The one I'm using now is just `bool b = MyMathLibrary.Sin(0f) < 100f;`.  Performance is not a concern.

Motivation:
I have some code which should only execute on a certain platform.
The natural way to code this up would be something like

```
#if IS_COMPILING_FOR_SPECIAL_PLATFORM
int bar = 123;
foo(bar);
#endif
```

However, I'm developing in Unity, and when developing the code, Visual Studio is not configured for IS_COMPILING_FOR_SPECIAL_PLATFORM, which means that the code in the #IF is not compiled.  This introduces development slowdown and maintenance overhead when something which foo() depends on changes. ie, instead of getting a compilation error right away, I have to wait for the larger and slower build pipeline.

So instead I'd like to do something like

```
#if IS_COMPILING_FOR_SPECIAL_PLATFORM
bool isSpecialPlatform = true;
#else
bool isSpecialPlatform = false;
#endif

if (isSpecialPlatform) {
  int bar = 123;
  foo(bar);
}
```

I'd be happy with this, except I get compiler warnings about 1) Unreachable code and 2) Unused variable bar (because it's in unreachable code I assume).
I can squelch the Unreachable Code warning with a `#pragma warning disable`, but I'd prefer not to introduce a blanket warning-disable for the unused variables in the code section, because that would squelch any legitimate warnings in the future.

I expect there will be at least one "you're asking the wrong question"-type reply, and I'm looking forward to hearing those suggestions as well.

Comment: `static class PlatformFlags { public static readonly bool IsSpecial = true; }`. IL containing the conditionals will remain, but the JIT will eliminate it at runtime (as if you had used a compile-time constant).

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you Jeroen.